# Why am I banned from asking questions?

Tags: discussion

Why am I banned from asking questions? I am certain all of them are good. Most of them have a positive score. Most of them are not closed. Considering the fact that we have a pandemic going on, I find this irresponsible. Everyone should be able to solicit advice under these circumstances. EVEN IF a question doesn't comply with the high standards adopted here. Not everywhere people have easy access to professional medical advice. Help out, not shut out

[image]

Comment: [This question is answered quite thoroughly on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/391772).

Comment: I don't believe it really addresses the issue

Comment: Actually, it does address the issue. A question ban has been imposed by the system just as it was last July, and for the same reasons. You had two more questions closed in October and that's on top of several more earlier this year and last year. I see that most were closed as requests for personal medical advice, but a few were closed as being unclear or other issues. The thing is, you never attempt to fix the problems, and that's why you're getting question bans. When one of your questions is closed, read the reason why and attempt to fix it. If you just leave it, it will eventually [cont]

Comment: be deleted by the system, and that counts against you. I highly recommend you read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) very carefully. Note in particular that asking for medical advice is strictly off topic and will be closed immediately. Everything else I usually offer a warning first to give you a chance to fix the problems. Please don't ignore those warnings.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I would be tempted to have this question closed as a duplicate of the Meta.SE question you linked

Comment: @ChrisRogers To close as a duplicate the question has to exist here.

Comment: You completely missed my point

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev No, you missed the point. There's nothing I or anyone else here can do about this. I did not impose a question ban on you and neither did any of the other moderators here. It was imposed by the system. You need to take your complaint to meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @careygregory has artificial intelligence already taken over? Is it some sort of Skynet you don't control? What does it mean, "the system did it"?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev It means a computer made the decision, not a person. This is explained in the link shown in the first comment above https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/391772

Comment: Also, it appears that the question ban has expired so you can ask questions again, but I recommend that you make sure you understand the guidelines of this site before doing so.

Comment: @CareyGregory it's not true (https://ibb.co/554ncky)

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev You're right, there is still a question ban on you on the main site. But again, I didn't impose it and there's nothing I can do about it. The link in the very first comment of this thread explains it.